# Sending args from bash to perl

Tags: bash, perl

I eally need help

I would like to send args from bash file to perl file. I dont know why it is not working for me. My code foe testing is bellow

*******bash code *********

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

chmod +x ../../../utils/run.pl
../../../utils/run.pl 1 2 3
```

******** perl *******

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#---------------------#
#  PROGRAM:  argv.pl  #
#---------------------#

$numArgs = $#ARGV + 1;
print "thanks, you gave me $numArgs command-line arguments:\n";

foreach $argnum (0 .. $#ARGV) {
    print "$ARGV[$argnum]\n";
}
```

******* result ***

```
thanks, you gave me 0 command-line arguments:
```

Any help please ???

Comment: This works just fine for me and reports three arguments. However I have noticed that you call `run.pl` in your bash but the comment in your Perl suggests that the filename is actually `argv.pl`. Not sure if that is relevant?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is your case, but such thing may happen on Windows.
I believe cmd.exe does not pass arguments to scripts if one's extension is not in `PATHEXT` environment variable.
Even if it is registered with `ASSOC`:

```
    assoc .pl=PerlScript
    ftype PerlScript=C:\bin\cygwin64\bin\perl.exe "%%1" %%*
```

However you can still run your script via

```
    # perl script.pl args
```

Also this kind of calling method allows you to skip chmod

Another wild guess is that your `env` produces some strange version of perl executable. You may want to check if result is legit at all. `which -a perl` is another helpful tool here.